# Is it possible to output the numpad's pattern using loops?

Tags: c, design-patterns, printing, nested-loops

I just started learning C (coding in general) a few months ago. Earlier today when I was in class, I looked at the numpad and wondered whether I would be able to replicate the pattern using nested loops in C.

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3 // This pattern.
```

I tried to do it myself for a bit, using for loops primarily. Thanks for any help.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row, col, i;

printf("Up to what integer? ");
scanf("%d", &row);

for(i=1; i<=row; i++)
{
    for(col=1; col<=10; col++)
    {
        printf(" %d ", i*col);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Edit: Added supplementary code. Something like this, except to print 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: Sure it is possible. What have you tried so far and were are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried with integers i, x, y; with for loops i =1. I've tried with the base number being 9 and 1.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without code its pointless to guess that your problem is. Also include the wrong output you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpad pattern has the equation `3*i + j` with `i` going from `2` to `0` and `j` going from `1` to `3`.

So use these values as upper and lower limits of `i` and `j` in nested `for` loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--){
        for(int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            printf("%d ", 3 * i + j);
        printf("\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

See it live [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50010c24ff58b0df).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  for(int j = 3; j > 0; --j)
    printf("%d ", (10 - j) - i * 3);

  printf("\n");
}
```